# React via ES6 classes. Why it work?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a question. Perhaps a little silly.

For example i have class, with *state* and *baseState*, who linked to state inside construcor

```
class SomeStrangeClass extends Component { 
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      confirmError:[],
    };
    this.baseState = this.state;
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log(this.state); //here i can have, for example, 3 confirmErrors...
    console.log(this.baseState); // here i still have an empty array
    this.setState(this.baseState);
  }
...some strange code
}
```

Of course it is good for me. Simple reset of state))) 
But..why **this.basestate** is empty, meanwhile **this.state** is not.

Why javascript behaves as if did not create a reference to the object?

Thank you very mutch!

Comment: By empty, do you mean that `baseState` is undefined, or that the `confirmError` array is empty? I don't agree with the answers, below, you _are_ making a reference to `this.state` in the `constructor`, however React's immutability naturally kills that reference with `setState`, as expected. Yet your original ref is intact: https://codepen.io/mikechabot/pen/pRVVpy?editors=0001

Comment: Hello lux! Thank you for attention!

Are you saying that if I made a reference to any object in the constructor (not the state), and then to change it through a simple assignment, then the referenced object would change? - https://codepen.io/Tbutnyakov/pen/bgMyyo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
this.baseState = this.state;
```

you are defining the completely new property of that `React.Component` class.

I the constructor means at the specific time when you initialize your `React.Component` object they will be equal.

It is a JavaScript feature to add new properties to any object dynamically.

Later on, when you execute `setState()` method of the Component class only the predefined `state` property will update and not the other one.

Here is the part of the source code for the `React.Component` :

```
/**
 * Module for creating composite components.
 *
 * @class ReactClass
 */
var ReactClass = {

  createClass: function(spec) {
    // To keep our warnings more understandable, we'll use a little hack here to
    // ensure that Constructor.name !== 'Constructor'. This makes sure we don't
    // unnecessarily identify a class without displayName as 'Constructor'.
    var Constructor = identity(function(props, context, updater) {
      // This constructor gets overridden by mocks. The argument is used
      // by mocks to assert on what gets mounted.

      if (__DEV__) {
        warning(
          this instanceof Constructor,
          'Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or ' +
          'JSX instead. See: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/legacy-factories.html'
        );
      }

      // Wire up auto-binding
      if (this.__reactAutoBindPairs.length) {
        bindAutoBindMethods(this);
      }

      this.props = props;
      this.context = context;
      this.refs = emptyObject;
      this.updater = updater || ReactNoopUpdateQueue;

      this.state = null;
```

just to visualize what is inside the component.

Comment: Thank you, prosti!

Answer (score 1):

When you do the assignment `this.baseState = this.state`, you are assigning the value of `this.state` **at that time** to the variable `this.baseState`, essentially making a copy. If `this.state` is updated with new variables after this, it does not reflect in the copy you made before.

Comment: Thank you, Mattia!